# Xamarin: Binding grouped RadioButton isChecked property with a viewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just to be clear I'm talking here about the [RadioButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton) released with Xamarin 4.6 in 2006.

My aim here is to create one binding which will work with multiple RadioButtons in the same group. Ultimately so I can leave my screen and come back to it and set the last selected RadioButton item.

So I know you can set a true of false property binding to the `IsChecked` property. However, this single item has no context of which item it is.

I know you can also set a binding context to a page or a control... so I guess I could set a context to a StackLayout for all the items inside it... but this still won't help.

This is something like what I want to achieve... yes I won't acctually have 10, I'm just making a point that I don't want to have to use lots of different bindings..

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Numbers" Text="One" 
  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedNumbersgroup}" />

<RadioButton GroupName="Numbers" Text="Two" 
  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedNumbersgroup}" />
....
<RadioButton GroupName="Numbers" Text="Ten" 
  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedNumbersgroup}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we binding the same source with multi **RadioButton** , it will cause issue as when you click one of them , other RadioButton will also been effected .

So in your case if you do not want to define multi property , you could define a List and binding them with the item .

#### in Xaml

**Command**,  which is executed when the RadioButton is selected.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Numbers" Text="One" IsChecked="{Binding MySource[0]}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="0" />

<RadioButton GroupName="Numbers" Text="Two" IsChecked="{Binding MySource[1]}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="1" />

<RadioButton GroupName="Numbers" Text="Three" IsChecked="{Binding MySource[2]}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="2" />
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<bool> MySource { get; set; }
```

```
public xxxViewModel()
        {
            MySource = new ObservableCollection<bool>() {true,false,false };

            ButtonCommand = new Command((org)=> {

 
                var index = int.Parse(org.ToString());

                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Title","the status of RadioButton"+(index+1).ToString()+"is"+MySource[index].ToString()  ,"OK");

            });

        }
```

Comment: Xamarin 5.0, we don't have 'Command' property for radio button. Is there any alternative option for this ?

Comment: Yeah they also have removed the text prop odd to say least